# Vue3/Quasar. 'q-' custom elements aren't recognized as quasar's elements

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

After updating package.json Vue started trying to resolve Quasar's components, and even if those are excluded (through vue.config.js) Quasar itself doesn't see them

console error

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: q-page-container
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
> at

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.13.0",
    "@vue/cli": "^5.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "quasar": "^2.5.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~4.0.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you install the framework? Did you import the framework correctly?

Comment: used *vue add quasar*
all quasar files are there, but css styles aren't applied as quasar doesn't see/recognize its 'q-' elements

Answer (score 0):

*For the future generations*

The issue is in vue/cli. Vue/cli is in the maintenance mode and it was replaced by Vite and apparently something inside vue/cli not supporting something in the new libs.

To upgrade from vue/cli to vite these are helpful manuals:

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/from-vue-cli-to-vitejs-648d2f5e031d
(note WebStorm hack for @ aliases)

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/

Also note that Vite doesn't support `require('path' / 'module')`, only `import`